# Bxslider in Chrome broke css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have on page slider

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.items_list').bxSlider({

    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 375,
    nextText: '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/arrow_right.png">',
    prevText: '<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/arrow_left.png">'   
  });
});
```

And style for div

```
.container-main {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1180px;
}
```

When I refresh page with f5 div under slider container-main stop work. When I push for example f11 it is ok. When I pust ctrl + f5 it is ok and then f5 and again broke.

Problem is only in google chrome

Please can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: Did you check the console? Did you see any JavaScript error there? We need see your code.

Comment: Please add a link to page where bxslider is broken. This code seems to be ok.

Comment: Hello thank you for your aswer I find the problem and solved it. On slide I have set margin-right and last slider drop under slider and broke do footer. I change it on padding and now works :)